# Cron expression for every 6 hours in a day

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch, jobs

What should be the cron expression to run a job at 6am, 12 noon, 6pm and 12 midnight everyday?
I am using the following in AWS Cloudwatch rule. It is not accepting the cron expression - 0 */6 * * *
Getting the following message - "Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid"

Comment: "not working properly" - what does it do then? How did you test it to (not) work?

Comment: FWIW, this appears to be right. You could also use `0,6,12,18` for hours, or just four crontab entries to make it simple and clear.

Comment: @domen I am giving the expression in AWS Cloudwatch rule. It is not accepting the cron expression.

Comment: That might be **a bit** relevant. From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html "Cron expressions have **six** required fields, which are separated by white space."

Comment: Wierd,  0 */6 * * *  is  corerct. I gues you have some kind of environment problems

Comment: @domen Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Used the following cron job - 0 */6 * * ? *
Worked perfectly.